# How to alert if 2 pods of same deployment running in same server GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have 3 pods running in 3 servers. 3 pods are from same deployment.I want alert if 2 pods run in 1 node itself. Is it is possible to create alert in Stackdriver. Is it is possible to make use of kubectl get pods -o wide -n mynamespace in Stackdriver for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an alert if 2 pods run in 1 node, but you can achieve to max 1 pod spawn on specific nodes using a deployment object with feature [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#example-one-topologyspreadconstraint)

For example [can use](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/) Pod Topology Spread Constraint based on a label key for your nodes, the label could be `type` and the value could be `regular`

You can also use a `maxSkew` value, which are the maximum differentiation of a number of pods that one label value (node type) can have, if you set it to 1, will enforce a limit of max 1 pod per node.

You can have something like this:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: type
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector: regular
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: myimage
```

As the feature name "PodTopologySpread" implies, the basic usage of this feature is to run your workload with an absolute even manner (maxSkew=1), or relatively even manner (maxSkew>=2), in addition to this basic usage, there are some advanced usage along with [PodAffinity/AntiAffinity and NodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) , that enable your workloads to benefit on high availability and cluster utilization, all depending on what best fits your use case.

Note: This feature is [alpha in 1.16 and beta in 1.18](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40358#issuecomment-583798776). Beta features are enabled by default in GKE, but with alpha features you'll need an [alpha cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-alpha-cluster) in GKE.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!